# On Atiyah-Singer Index theorem and Atiyah-Bott fixed point theorem.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

I would like to understand the *statement* of Atiyah-Singer and Atiyah-Bott theorems enough to see lots and lots of applications they have. My background is pretty thin with some basic algebraic topology ( fundamental group and singular homology ) some familiarity with manifolds and vector bundles but no characteristic classes or K-theory or cobordism. I know some distributions but nothing about psuedo-differential operators.

I am willing to spend a few weeks getting to know the definitions and main examples and theorems. I am okay with not knowing the proofs but I want to be able to convince myself with lots and lots of examples and applications of these results.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the index theorem you should learn about characteristic classes but there's no need to learn about pseudodifferential operators; already the index theorem for Dirac operators has many applications.